# Convert multidimensional array into something useful to submit data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a multidimentional array that is generated by:

```
 $('#order-submit').click(function(){
    var orderResult = [];
    $(".dynamic-sale").each(function(){
        var individual_result = [];
        $(this).find("select").each(function(){
            individual_result.push($(this).val());
        })
        orderResult.push(individual_result);
    });
```

It collects data from a dynamic form of shirt sales, and creates an array that looks like:
      [["3XL", "1", "15"], ["XL", "1", "15"]]
Which is the size, quantity and price per item for each row. I was able to calculate the total cost, but I'm having a hard time figuring out a way to get the total quantity of each item into a format that I can then add to an ajax call to submit to the database. How would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? What does the data need to look like when the server gets the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// I added an element to your array for testing purposes
var arr = [["3XL", "1", "15"], ["XL", "1", "15"], ["XL", "2", "15"]]

// create an object to store each item
var items = {}

// loop over the array, building object with totals
$.each(arr, function(i,v){
    // if the item is not already defined, then define it
    if(typeof items[v[0]] == 'undefined')
        // the `- 0` ensures that the value is treated as numeric
        items[v[0]] = v[1] - 0
    // else increment it
    else
        items[v[0]] += v[1] - 0
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I recomend you to use jQuery `.serialize()` to send the form and calculate it server side:
http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/